# Possibly new multivariate polynomials associated to finite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, polynomials

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a finite graph, where $V$ is a finite set of vertices and $E$ is a finite set of unoriented edges. We assume that $G$ has no loops, i.e. that there is no edge joining a vertex to itself. While our construction of
the multivariate polynomials can handle multiple edges between two different vertices, yet, for simplicity, we shall assume that each edge is simple.

Assume, say, that $V = [\mathbf{n}] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$. It does seem like we are assuming that $V$ is linearly ordered, yet in the end, our polynomials will be independent of the choice of linear order on $V$, apart from a sign factor.
Corresponding to the elements of $V$, let $x_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ be $n$ abstract variables.

Given a vertex $i \in V$, denote by $N(i) \subseteq V \setminus \{i\}$ the set of neighboring vertices to $i$. To each pair $(i,j)$, where $i \in V$ and $j \in N(i)$, we associate

$$ (p^{ij}_{A_{ij}}) = \left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ x_j \end{array} \right) $$

where $A_{ij} = 1,2$ (here $ij$ is just a label). To each vertex $i \in V$, we then associate

$$ p^i_{A_{ij_1},\ldots,A_{ij_{\kappa}}} = p^{ij_1}_{(A_{ij_1}} \cdots p^{ij_{\kappa}}_{A_{ij_{\kappa}})}$$

where the indices $j_1, \ldots, j_{\kappa}$ are the elements in $N(i)$, $\kappa = |N(i)|$ and where the parentheses enclosing indices indicate symmetrization. For example,

$$\rho_{(A}\nu_{B)} = \rho_A \nu_B + \rho_B \nu_A$$
$$\rho_{(ABC)} = \rho_{ABC} + \rho_{ACB} + \rho_{BAC} + \rho_{BCA} + \rho_{CAB} + \rho_{CBA}.$$

We then define

$$ p_{A_{1j_1}\ldots A_{1j_{\kappa}} \ldots A_{nl_1} \ldots A_{nl_{\mu}}} = p^1_{A_{1j_1}\ldots A_{1j_{\kappa}}} \cdots p^n_{A_{nl_1}\ldots A_{nl_{\mu}}} $$

where $j_1, \ldots, j_{\kappa}$ are the elements of $N(1)$ with $\kappa = |N(1)|$ and $l_1,\ldots, l_{\mu}$ are the elements of $N(n)$ with $\mu = |N(n)|$.

Let
$$ (\omega^{AB}) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array} \right). $$
We will use $\omega$ to contract pairs of indices.

We define

$$I_G = (\prod_{(i,j) \in E} \omega^{A_{ij}A_{ji}}) p_{A_{1j_1}\ldots A_{1j_{\kappa}} \ldots A_{nl_1} \ldots A_{nl_{\mu}}}$$

where we are assuming that each edge in $E$ is written as $(i,j)$ where $1 \leq i < j \leq n$, and where we have used Einstein's summation convention.

The polynomial $I_G$ associated to a finite graph $G$ has the following properties.

1. The polynomial $I_G$ is well defined up to a sign factor.
2. The polynomial $I_G$ is homogenous in the $x_i$ of degree equal to the number of edges in $G$.
3. If $\sigma$ is a permutation of $V$ which preserves the graph structure (a symmetry of the graph), then, upon acting on the variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, we have
   $$ \sigma.I_G = \pm I_G, $$
   where the sign factor can be determined from $\sigma$ and $G$.
4. If $G = G_1 + G_2$ is the disjoint union of two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$, then $I_G = I_{G_1} I_{G_2}$. In other words, $I_G$ is multiplicative.
5. If $G = K_n$ is the complete graph on $n$ vertices, then $I_G$ is an integer multiple of the Vandermonde determinant. In other words,
   $$ I_G = c_n \prod_{i < j} (x_j - x_i) $$
   for some nonzero $c_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ depending on $n$ only.

Our first example is $K_3$, the complete graph on $3$ vertices. We then obtain

$$ I_{K_3} = 4 \prod_{1 \leq i<j \leq 3} (x_i - x_j). $$

Our second example consists of $G = (V,E)$ with $V = [\mathbf{3}]$ (so that $n = 3$) and $E = \{ (1,2), (1,3) \}$. We then get

$$ I_G =  2(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3).$$

Our third example is $K_4$, the complete graph on $4$ vertices. We then obtain

$$ I_{K_4} = 144 \prod_{1 \leq i<j \leq 4} (x_i - x_j). $$

Our fourth example is $G = (V,E)$ with $V = [\mathbf{4}]$ (so that $n = 4$) and $E = \{ (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4) \}$ (G is the complete $(2,2)$ bipartite graph). Then

$$ I_G = 16 x_{1}^{2} x_{2}^{2} - 16 x_{1}^{2} x_{2} x_{3} - 16 x_{1}^{2} x_{2} x_{4} + 2 x_{1}^{2} x_{3}^{2} + 12 x_{1}^{2} x_{3} x_{4} + 2 x_{1}^{2} x_{4}^{2} - 16 x_{1} x_{2}^{2} x_{3} - 16 x_{1} x_{2}^{2} x_{4} + 12 x_{1} x_{2} x_{3}^{2} + 40 x_{1} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4} + 12 x_{1} x_{2} x_{4}^{2} - 16 x_{1} x_{3}^{2} x_{4} - 16 x_{1} x_{3} x_{4}^{2} + 2 x_{2}^{2} x_{3}^{2} + 12 x_{2}^{2} x_{3} x_{4} + 2 x_{2}^{2} x_{4}^{2} - 16 x_{2} x_{3}^{2} x_{4} - 16 x_{2} x_{3} x_{4}^{2} + 16 x_{3}^{2} x_{4}^{2}$$

What I would like to know is:

1. Are these polynomials new?
2. Are they interesting? Are they worth studying? If so, what kind of information about a graph do they hold?

Edit 1: Kindly note that I have changed the definition of $I_G$ from my earlier definition (please look at the new definition of the $p^{ij}$).

Edit 2 (in response to @AbdelmalekAbdesselam's comments): I will here define a similar (but different!) quantity where we have $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ invariance. Given a finite graph $G = (V,E)$ and a configuration of $n$ distinct points $[x_i \, y_i] \in \mathbb{P}^1$ (over the complex numbers), one may associate a complex number $Z_G$ in the following way.

Label the vertex $i$ with the point $\zeta_i = [x_i \, y_i] \in \mathbb{P}^1$. Define $I_G(x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_n,y_n)$ same as above, except one should use the homogeneous version

$$ p^{ij} = \left( \begin{array}{c} x_j \\ y_j \end{array} \right) $$.

The rest of the definition remains the same. But then we have an issue, namely each set of homogenous coordinates is only defined up to a nonzero complex scaling factor. We thus define

$$ J_G(x_1,y_1, \ldots, x_n, y_n) = \prod_{(i,j) \in E}(x_iy_j-x_jy_i).$$

Then

$$ Z_G = I_G/J_G $$

is a well defined rational function of the $\zeta_i\,$s. It is also clear that $Z_G$ is $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$-invariant.

Edit 3: I think I will study some of its combinatorial properties and then decide whether or not it is worth publishing. I know the notation is a hurdle here, but I did my best to write things down and explain. Anyway, we will see... For the reader who is reading the comments, kindly note that I have changed the notation from $V_G$ to $I_G$, which is a bit more standard (I have also changed the notation from $W_G$ to $J_G$).

Edit 4: Ok, I now understand reasonably well these polynomials. First, one may define them in an alternative way. I will sketch a little bit how. Given an oriented graph, one can generate other oriented graphs using what I call "neighbor ambiguity". I don't know what is the best way to explain it yet, but roughly speaking, I define $2$ oriented graphs $(V,E_1)$ and $(V,E_2)$ with the same set of vertices $V$ and same number of edges to be neighbor-equivalent with respect to $(V,E)$ (where $|E| = |E_1| = |E_2|$) if there is a bijective map, say $f$, from $E_1$ onto $E_2$, such that given any edge $e_1 \in E_1$, the source of $e_1$ is a neighbor of the source of $f(e_1)$ in $(V,E)$ and the target of $e_1$ is a neighbor of the target of $f(e_1)$ in $(V,E)$.

Given $G = (V,E)$ as above, we consider the finite set $\mathcal{C}$ of graphs which are neighbor-equivalent to $G$ with respect to $G$. Then $I_G$ is the sum of the graph polynomials of the graphs in $\mathcal{C}$.

So they are sums of graph polynomials of some kind of orbit of $G$. When you expand $I_G$, the coefficient of each term counts the signed number of a given type of oriented subgraphs in the collection $\mathcal{C}$.

I don't know if the notion of neighbor-equivalence (with respect to a finite graph $G$) has any concrete applications. If I find one, then I may consider publishing this, otherwise, it will just go to oblivion.

Has anyone seen something similar to this notion of neighbor-equivalence? Does it have any concrete interprations/applications?

Comment: Hi Joseph, this is possibly a great question but the way it is written it is very unclear, because of the Bourbakization. Can you add a completely elementary definition of $V_G$, i.e., withouth using $\otimes,\odot$ and letting tensors just be matrices with lots of indices. It seems to me you are trying to define an $SL_2$ invariant of $n$ points in $\mathbb{P}^1$ with homogeneous coordinates $[x_i,y_i]$ which you dehomogenized from the get go by letting $y_i=1$. If so, I should be able to tell you if this is known once the formula is clear to me.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, I rewrote the definition of $V_G$. Is it clearer now please? Thank you for your interest!

Comment: And you are right. One can view it as kind of invariant of graphs or, dually, view it as an $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$-invariant for $n$ distinct points on $\mathbb{P}^1$. Well, to be strictly correct, one needs to divide $V_G$ by the graph polynomial of $G$ or, if you prefer, by a similar quantity to $V_G$ but constructed without the complete symmetrization step in the definition of the $p_i$.

Comment: Thanks. It's much clearer in the sense I now understand the algorithm and can compute $V_G$ including the signs and coefficients like $8,-6,\ldots$. But I don't yet have a bird's eye view. At first sight it actually does not look like an invariant but a covariant rather, i.e., an invariant involving an extra point sitting at infinity.

Comment: It seems you divided by $W_G$ just to have a strict (modern?) definition of invariant, i.e., no ambiguity with respect to rescaling of homogeneous coordinates, i.e., forming an absolute invariant. This is not necessary for what classical invariant theorists meant by "invariant". The slight issue I had is that the terms generated do not have consistent homogeneity in each point and they sit in different multigraded pieces.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, I think I understand your point, but please note that I have modified my definition. Now $p^{ij}$ is just $(1 \, x_j)$ (rather than what I had before, which was $(1 \, x_i - x_j)$. Does that fix the issues you are talking about?